# Unable to load knp_paginator bundle

Tags: symfony, pagination

I am getting the following error when I try to clear the cache in Symfony:

> "Cannot import resource C:...\config.yml from "C:...\config_dev.yml"
>   (There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "knp_paginator")..."

And it goes on to say:

> "Looked for namespace "knp_paginator", found "framework", "security",
>   "twig", etc etc"

It happens when I put the config settings suggested at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle into my config.yml file:

```
# Pagination
knp_paginator:
    page_range: 5                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig # sort link template
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discovered what it was:

I needed to add the bundle to the application kernel. In `app/AppKernel.php`, the function `registerBundles()` I needed to add:

```
new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
```

And that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

for symfony 5 : add
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class=> ['all' => true],

in config/bundles.php

Comment: With Symfony 5 all you have to do is require the package and the flex recipe would take care of the configuration. This applies to Symfony Flex that works for Symfony 3.3 and higher and it is a default and recommended structure from version 4. Also, the bundle documentation clearly explains that explicit bundle registration is needed only for non-flex projects. Consider adding some context why you had to do this manually.